# How to show that $e^{1/z}$ takes every value in C*.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that $e^{1/z}$, takes an value in to complex plane besides zero, if we restrict ourselves to arbitrary small values around the origin.

That is,  for any $\epsilon$ if $|z|<\epsilon$ and c is a complex number, so that c is not zero, then there is a z smaller than $\epsilon$ such that $e^{1/z}=c$. Here is my attempt:

Let $e^{1/z}=c$, write $z=re^{i*\theta}, c=le^{i\eta}$.

Then we get:

$e^{1/r*e^{-i\theta}}=e^{1/r*(\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta))}=le^{i\eta}$.
Then we must have:

$e^{\cos(\theta)/r}=l$ and $e^{-i\sin(\theta)/r}=e^{i\eta}$.

This gives:

$\cos(\theta)/r=\ln(l)$, and$-i\sin(\theta)/r=\eta$.

Now I get stuck.

Can these two equations be solved, with also requiring that $r < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon?$

Comment: What about Great Picard's Theorem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem

Comment: @Timbuc Yes this is an example of picards theorem with an essential singularity.

Comment: Picard's theorem is, however, nuking a mosquito. Can you translate the problem into a question about $e^z$? From the known properties of $e^z$, the answer follows easily.

Comment: Hint: For any $r>0,\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ take $z^{-1} = \log r + i\theta$ then $e^{\frac{1}{z}} = re^{i\theta}$ (for $r=1$, $\theta=0$ take $\theta=2\pi$ instead). Conclude from there.

Comment: @DanielFischer I only then get that $e^{\bar{z}/|z|^2}=c$?

Comment: Let $w = \frac{1}{z}$. If $0 < \lvert z\rvert < \epsilon$, then $\lvert w\rvert$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Then |w| is bigger than $1/\epsilon$. So I guess if you write $e=a+bi$, then a is determined by the length of c, and you just choose b big enough to get w big enough?

Comment: You want to show that for every $a \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, there is a $w\in \mathbb{C}$ with $\lvert w\rvert > 1/\epsilon$ and $e^w = a$. Why does such a $w$ exist?

Comment: @DanielFischer if $w = n+mi$, choose $n=ln(|a|)$, and $m=arg(a)+2*\pi*10^{999}(or bigger)$.

Comment: Yes. The exponential function maps each strip $u \leqslant \operatorname{Im} w < u+2\pi$ bijectively to $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Since the complement of a disk contains infinitely many (disjoint) such strips, it attains each nonzero value infinitely often in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{D_R(0)}$ for every $R > 0$. Hence $e^{1/z}$ attains each nonzero value infinitely often in every punctured disk $0 < \lvert z\rvert < \epsilon$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much for your help!